# how to connect to the local server in Oracle 11g expres edition?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I 'm trying to set up a local server, for use with SQL Developer to practice consultations, I have installed oracle 11g express edition for Windows 7 64-bit .

I have installed and reinstalled several times , I checked the firewall and Antivurus and everything is correct .

The problem is that once installed will give the Get Started icon to connect
" http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950 " and I get an error in the browser.

Is there any way to easily configure the SQL Developer locally to store and query schemes ?

How I can solve the problem to access this page http : //127.0.0.1 : 8080 / apex / f p = 4950 "?

thanks

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950 cannot start and the SQL Developer , when entering the username and password to connect to the database , not allowing me to connect .